# how to use page load method call in mvc?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

i wan to call mvc controller method while page load :

```
    public ActionResult Detail(int id)
    {
       Customer customer =  CustomerManager.GetCustomer(id);
        return View(customer);
    }
```

My View Codes :

```
<h2>Detail</h2>
<%=Html.ValidationSummary("Please correct the erros and try again.") %>
   <% using (Html.BeginForm("Detail", "Customer", new { id = 1 }))
      {%>
<fieldset>
<legend>Fields</legend>
<p>
<%=Html.LabelFor(q => q.id)%>
<%=Html.Encode(Model.id)%>
</p>
<p>
<%=Html.LabelFor(q => q.Name)%>
<%=Html.DisplayFor(q => q.Name)%>
</p>
<p>
<%=Html.LabelFor(q => q.SurName)%>
<%:Html.Encode(Model.SurName)%>
</p>
<p>
 <%=Html.ActionLink("Edit", "Edit", new { id = Model.id })%> 
</p>

</fieldset>
<%} %>
```

How to Call Detail action method :

Classic Web Form :

```
Pageload()
{
  if(!ispostback)
       Detail(1);
}
```

TO

MVC from . How to do that?

Comment: you can write your referrer url to session. each request, check if the referrer url string equal request.url then call Detail(id). Since MVC is stateless, I think there is no postback property.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
if (true) // some condition
{
    return RedirectToAction("Detail", "Customer", new { id = 1 });
}
```

Comment: this will also(as a side effect) render the view associated with the detail method, but not render the view associated with the original request

Comment: Yes, you're right. This's for view <%=Html.Action("Detail", "Customer", new { id = 1 }) %>